# How can I prevent an industrial revolution from destroying a magitech society?

Tags: technological-development, balancing-magic-systems, industrial-age

Testosterone and estrogen are two important chemicals for the Drow in regards to magic. Estrogen allows one to be conductors of magic, while testosterone allows one to be conduits for it. Because of this, female elves have the ability to create magical items through the use of spells (applying runes, transmutation, alchemy, etc).This gives items expanded abilities, and forms the basis of magitech in civilization. However, due to their low testosterone levels, their poor conduocity prevents them from completely utilizing items with magical properties. Male Drow in contrast produce hundreds of times the level of testosterone than their counterparts, which make them far better conductors. Items become more capable in their hands at whatever they were designed to do (knives become sharper, armor is stronger, etc). Society develops along separate balances of power, with females creating magitech and males operating and using them.

In our world, the industrial revolution was a pivotal event which introduced changes into society. This transition moved us away from hand production methods to machines, new chemical manufacturing and iron production processes, the increasing use of steam power and water power, the development of machine tools and the rise of the mechanized factory system. Automation eventually became the norm, as things that were once done by humans could now be done by machines much faster and better.

If a similar period entered this world, it would most likely disrupt balances of power, as everything that males and females can do will be automated by technology. What I want is to have a magitech period which saw a Renaissance of increased productivity, but also keeping the status quo of the balance of power between the sexes. What changes would make sense under these conditions and how can elves compensate for these changes?

Comment: Why the paragraph about that hormone babble? It makes this question hard to read. The idea that industrial revolution just happens sounds a bit off to say it nicely. The question shouldn't be "what happens when a major change in society randomly happens" but first "what changes make sense and how do people compensate". The current answer already gives you a preview of the benefits of a structured approach. Automation doesn't happen over night and it doesn't happen in everything equally. Why not take a step back and first build a solid foundation to your world?

Comment: You do understand that both men and women have both oestrogen and testosterone, right? It's the balance which is different. (And it's yet again different in pre-pubescent people and in post-menopausal women.) And what about poor oxytocin? Why is it always left out when speaking of "sex" hormones? (And no, male Drow, whatever they are, do not produce "hundreds of times" more testosterone than female Drow; excess testosterone is not conducive to a long and balanced life.)

Comment: @Raditz_35 so erase everything about sex hormones ?

Answer (score 3):

We don't have "full automation" in our world, and it is unlikely such a thing will ever occur.  In the second industrial revolution, where machining really took over, the "assembly-line production" model proved powerful.  This did not *eliminate* human involvement, just changed *what* the humans did.  For example, rather than a blacksmith having to melt and hammer an axe into shape, a machine could melt and pour the metal into molds.  Human involvement turned into (a) operating the machines which performed these functions, (b) fastening the axe head into the handle base, and (c) sealing the package for shipment/delivery.

In your world, it's similar.  The females are required to *operate* the machinery because only they can conduct, but the machinery needs men in/on/near/whatever to increase the strength of the machine.  Thus the balance of power is the same, as men can't *conduct* magic therefore they cannot *operate* the machine.

It's worth noting that the industrial revolutions were designed and gained popularity by making people's lives *a little bit easier*.  This did not eradicate the need for human involvement; in fact, the number of jobs *increased* because of the industrial revolutions.  The economics of industrial revolutions isn't *that* complicated, but is too much for this answer.  Suffice it to say that there would be no incentive for industrial revolutions to take place in your world if it eliminated the need for magical conduction.  Factories only exist because people buy the products, and people only buy the products because it benefits them.

So the machines, equipment, factories, relationships between managements and corporations would be designed *around what exists*, it would most definitely not *replace them*.